# SQL How to add a column to a table that's the sum of a category's quantity

Tags: sql

I have a data table shaped like below:

[image]

What I'm looking to do with SQL is add a column that will be the sum for the total category by month without removing any rows. For Example,

[image]

My goal is to take this category data and do some calculations with it like dividing it by the Qty and seeing how it changes over time.

What I've tried to do is use GROUP BY the category and date but that ends up with me losing the Item level data which I want to compare the Category level data to.

I also tried doing something like this

```
SELECT
Item, Category, Date, Qty, (sum(QTY) from TABLE)
FROM TABLE
```

but that only gives the sum of the QTY for the whole column not split out by Month/Year and Category.

Does anyone know what might help? I'm relatively new to using SQL so I hope I explained my question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(qty) over (partition by category, date) as category_sum
from t;
```

This assumes that `date` is really just the month and year.  If it is the exact date, you need to extract the month and year from it.